# CSS Responsive text content

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have this button which contains `Upgrade my account`.

I'd like to have a rule that says for screens less than 990px, it should be `Upgrade` instead (as `Upgrade my account` is too long)...

Can I cleanly achieve that in CSS (not by adding both version and having one `display: none` while the other one is displayed ...) ?

I tried

```
  @media(max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-btn {
      content: 'Upgrade'
    }
  }
```

but it won't work...

Thanks

Comment: Don't put content in CSS, think about making your website localised in in different languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `span` and show/hide it according to the screen size:

HTML

```
<button class='navbar-btn'>
    Upgrade<span> my Account</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
@media(max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-btn span {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ke5Vp/)

Comment: This is the most elegant solution to me as all the content is in the html file and only the display logic is on the css side.

Answer (score 2):

See

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FaA7/)**

The `content` property only applies to the `:before` and `:after` psuedo elements, it also means you'll be putting content (the text) in your CSS..which I wouldnt tend to recommend..

HTML

```
<div class='navbar-btn'></div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-btn {
    position:relative;
}
.navbar-btn:after {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    content:'Upgrade my Account';
}
@media(max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-btn:after {
        content:'Upgrade';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Say your html is in the following

```
<div class="navbar">
    <span>Upgrade my account</span>
</div>
```

Your media query can be

```
@media(max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar:before {
      content: 'Upgrade'
    }
    .navbar > span {display:none;}
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eWWQN/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something along the way i did in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g64Xp/2)

CSS:

```
@media(min-width: 990px) {
  .navbar-btn:after {
    content: ' account'
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class='navbar-btn'>Upgrade</button>
```

Comment: Good solution and probably the more accurate, lighter and flexible method.